# webview/RNCWebViewManager.java:1214: error: method onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest) is already defined in class RNCWebChromeClient

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

```
buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30

OS: Windows 10
react-native version: ^0.64.
react-native-webview version: ^11.6.2
```

```js
// Fix WebRTC permission request error.
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
    String[] requestedResources = request.getResources();
    ArrayList < String > permissions = new ArrayList < > ();
    ArrayList < String > grantedPermissions = new ArrayList < String > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < requestedResources.length; i++) {
      if (requestedResources[i].equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE)) {
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
      } else if (requestedResources[i].equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
      } else if (requestedResources[i].equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID)) {
        permissions.add(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID);
      }
      // TODO: RESOURCE_MIDI_SYSEX, RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID.
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {

        grantedPermissions = new ArrayList < > ();

        ArrayList < String > requestedAndroidPermissions = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (String requestedResource: request.getResources()) {
          String androidPermission = null;

          if (requestedResource.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_AUDIO_CAPTURE)) {
            androidPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
          } else if (requestedResource.equals(PermissionRequest.RESOURCE_VIDEO_CAPTURE)) {
            androidPermission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
          }
          // TODO: RESOURCE_MIDI_SYSEX, RESOURCE_PROTECTED_MEDIA_ID.

          if (androidPermission != null) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mReactContext, androidPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
              grantedPermissions.add(requestedResource);
            } else {
              requestedAndroidPermissions.add(androidPermission);
            }
          }
        }
```

> webview/RNCWebViewManager.java:1214:  error: method onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest) is already defined in class RNCWebChromeClient

Answer (score 0):

please downgrade your react-native-webview version to **v11.5.4** or **11.3.2** . I have checked in v11.3.2 and it's working.

Ref: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2001

Hope it helped!

Comment: Why it's not working with updated version?